# How to manipulate Prestashop 1.7.x currency exchange rate using a fixed variable?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.7, opensymphony

In Prestashop 1.7 the auto currency exchange rate automatically updates the currency rates, but I would like to add a manipulation to the rates. For example 1 USD = 75 INR, but with a manipulation of 10%, I would want 1 USD = 75(1 + 10%) = 82.5 INR.

How to permanently add this manipulation of 10% such that whenever the live exchange rate button is clicked, the current exchange rate + 10% is calculated in the tables?

I could manually edit all the exchange rates by 10% but that is a tedious task so a permanent solution for the same would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Currency referesh cron is calling **Currency::refreshCurrencies()**  method,
that is calling refreshCurrency function inside */classes/currency.php*

So you can either edit or override this method to follow your 10% increase logic.